# Group Locust statistics by Task

Tags: python, testing, locust

My use-case involves two tasks in Locust that have overlapping endpoints. for e.g.

```
Fetch Task:
    fetch/
    response/{id}/

Update Task: 
    update/
    response/{id}/
```

Both tasks use the same `response/` endpoint; however, the statistics do not give me visibility into how long the `response/` endpoint takes for each type of task. Is there a way to group the statistics by task or some other way to approach this problem?

I am aware of grouping requests using the name keyword argument as shown here:

```
self.client.get("endpoint/", name="endpoint_name")
```

However, I cannot use this because all requests are made internally using a library.

Comment: That `name` argument is what you need. You will have to figure out how to include that in your calls. I'm not sure I understand how you would be unable to pass that arg if you're currently making calls and getting stats to Locust. Can you share more details?

Comment: The library I have built takes a session object as a kwarg. When running Locust, I pass in Locust's HTTP client object. `session.get()` does not have a `name` kwarg. So, I get:

`TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'` when using a `requests.Session` object

Answer (score 1):

`HttpSession`s `request_name` attribute is used to override request naming in your scenario.

```
self.client.request_name = "Fetch"
# call your sdk, requests will be named ”Fetch”
self.client.request_name = "Update"
# call your sdk again
```

See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#grouping-requests for more details.